# How to interpret the results of Generalised linear model(GLM), I have used Normal distribution with identity link function

Tags: generalized-linear-model, jmp

I am not sure about the quality of the model. I have searched but could not find a reliable answer.

Below is the model results from JMP

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to interpret a linear regression?  A normal likelihood with identity link is equivalent to a linear regression.

Comment: Yes, but there is no r square or RMSE numbers

Comment: Why not just fit a linear regression then?  I'm sure JMP will report those statistics in their linear regression routine

Comment: I found difference in a linear regression and the GLM with normal+identity combination. The number of significant IVs  are different in GLM than LR. The GLM results looks more accurate with the established theories so I thought to prefer this but I am not sure of goodness of model. I found significant IV but not sure of overall model

Comment: The differences are due to GLM using z tests rather than t tests for the coefficients.  You should not select models based on which give you significant results

Comment: Thanks for the information. To select model or process, I wanted to know whether the results of GLM are accurate or not. In case of LR, R2 and RMSE can suggest but here I am not sure. Please guide.

Comment: I've already noted that the two are equivalent and your preference for GLM because it gives you statistically significant results is not a valid approach to inference.

Comment: Then what should be the right approach. Selecting a model over other is based on fit statistics I think. In this case of GLM I am not sure about the fitness. Thats were I need help. Is this model fitting.

Comment: Any idea for this problem